# What is the meaning of “deceived of”?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> How beautiful a street is in winter! It is at once revealed and obscured. Here vaguely one can trace symmetrical straight avenues of doors and windows; here under the lamps are floating islands of pale light through which pass quickly bright men and women, who, for all their poverty and shabbiness, wear a certain look of unreality, an air of triumph, as if they had given life the slip, so that life, **deceived of** her prey, blunders on without them.

What is the meaning of “deceived of her prey”? Is it the same as “deceived **by** her prey”?

I can’t find the usage of “deceived of” in dictionary.

Comment: The writer means deprived of prey by means of deception.

Comment: @Bruce Murray Does “deceived of something” mean “deprived of something by deception” in general or just a rare usage here that somehow reader could understand due to context?

Comment: I'm giving you my best guess.  I have not previously encountered that verb preposition combination; maybe I should get out more.

Comment: @Bruce: That wouldn't help unless you're going out with your *Time Machine!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited usage is given in the [full Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48096?redirectedFrom=deceive#eid)<sup>1</sup> under definition 4...

> 4 a. *To cheat, overreach; defraud. **Obsolete.***
> 4 b. with of: *To cheat out of. **Obsolete.***

As [@Bruce](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252040/what-is-the-meaning-of-deceived-of#comment473740_252040) comments under the question, the writer  means ***deprived of prey by means of deception***. I think the writer here might be Virginia Woolf, so the text could be well over a century old. But it would have been a "poetic / literary / creative" usage even when written. Certainly modern-day learners shouldn't copy it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Subscription-only, I'm afraid!